# How do you create a test Stripe standard account that is in the "Complete" status?

Tags: stripe-payments

This is all in Test mode:

I've successfully created a standard connect account but it's restricted until the standard account accepts the TOS. The problem is that I created the account via the API and I don't have access (password) to login to the dashboard to accept the TOS. The account is in the rejected status until that happens. Further, I can't use oauth to connect my app because I can't login to the standard account.

I'm using this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/create) to create an account link to link my connect platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't need to do anything specific to that account and it just works in Test mode for all transactions. So trying to force it to be in a "complete" state is not really something you should try to do.

Overall though, you can create a new Standard Account, then use AccountLink to onboard that account as if you were an end user. You can do this in a separate browser or private browsing mode and sign up for the account, choose an email/password and provide all the information you would be expected to provide if you were really onboarding. You could do the same thing in Live mode with Live API keys too if you wanted to get a real account fully onboarded.

As a developer, I have my own Stripe account for my platform and I have multiple separate Stripe accounts connected to my platform (either via OAuth or onboarded as described above). That allows me to test various situations such as having connected accounts in different countries or with different settings. And each account has its own email pattern like `myaccount+testing-france@example.com` versus `myaccount+testing-canada@example.com` and such for me to easily switch between various situations.